# What is the relationship between R-squared and MS(Res)?

Tags: regression, self-study, residuals, r-squared

My textbook (Applied Regression Analysis: A Research Tool by Rawlings, Pantula, and Dickey) asks me to "Show algebraically the relationship between R-squared and MS(Res)", but I don't even know what this relationship should look like.

Comment: You should be able to figure out how they're related from equation 7.2. Alternatively start from $R^2=1-\frac{\text{SS(Res)}}{\text{SS(Tot)}}$ and derive it from the relationship between $\text{SS(Res)}$ and $\text{MS(Res)}$. However, it will also be in terms of some other quantity (SS(Tot), MS(Tot), SS(Reg) etc). I don't see it specified which they want in what I can see on Google books, though it's easy to move between them. You may be able to see something I can't

Comment: Are you saying, that MS(Res) is equal to SS(Total) * ((1-R^2)/(n-p'))?

Comment: There are several different ways you could write the relationship, and as I said, it's not 100% clear to me what is wanted (but I can't see the whole book).  In the case of the formula you just gave it may make more sense to write SS(Total) to a multiple of MS(Total) so that both terms are mean squares.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be the sample size, $y_i$ be the $i$th observation, $\hat y_i$ be the prediction of the $i$th observation, and $\bar y$ be the mean of all observations. A common definition of $R^2$ is below.

$$
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$

Next, it is typical to define $MSE$ as $\dfrac{1}{N}\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2$.

$$
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2 = N\times MSE\\
\bigg\Updownarrow\\
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
N\times MSE
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$